# nested xml tag to xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Can you help me on this?
I have an xml something like this

```
<x:person>
    <x:name>Angel</x:name>
    <x:education-info>
        <school>School ABC</school> 
        <address>address 123</address>
        <city>city 1</city> 
        <year>2001</year>
        <remarks>12334</remarks>
        <school>School ABC2</school>
        <address>address 456</address>
        <city>city 2</city>
        <year>2005</year>
        <remarks>test1233</remarks>
    </x:education-info>
    <x:age>22</x:age>
</x:person>
```

how can I get only school and address tag inside education-info tag ?
and format it to xslt something like this

```
School ABC - address 123
School ABC2 - address 456
```

Comment: Do you have a **specific** question?

Answer (score 1):

## XSLT 1.0

If I first make your XML valid XML, it will look something like the following, which has the effect that some elements are in namespace `urn:yourns` and some are in no namespace:

```
<x:person xmlns:x="urn:yourns">
    <x:name>Angel</x:name>
    <x:education-info>
        <school>School ABC</school> 
        <address>address 123</address>
        <city>city 1</city> 
        <year>2001</year>
        <remarks>12334</remarks>
        <school>School ABC2</school>
        <address>address 456</address>
        <city>city 2</city>
        <year>2005</year>
        <remarks>test1233</remarks>
    </x:education-info>
    <x:age>22</x:age>
</x:person>
```

Now, if you want data from this input, you will need to make sure to match the proper namespace in your XSLT. It does not have to match the prefix, as long as it matches the namespace.

The following code shows how to do this the "XSLT way" by using templates. This may look like more code than the first answer, but it is more resilient to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:your="urn:yourns"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- select 'text', as your output suggests you only want text -->
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <!-- ignore what we aren't interested in (this one is not req. with 
    your data, but help if your input is larger/different) -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <!-- match parent x:education-info to only select what we are interested in 
    (this one can be left out as well, but more cleanly shows what you want to do)-->
    <xsl:template match="your:education-info">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="school | address" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match school in no-namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="school">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match address in no-namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="address">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output, when run against your input is the following. [Check it online by clicking here](http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7kV).

```
School ABC - address 123
School ABC2 - address 456
```

---

## XSLT 3.0

For the fun of it, or mainly because your example is so clearly cut out for a call on `for-each-pair`, here's a one-liner (if you ignore the bloat) in XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:your="urn:yourns"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" />

    <xsl:template match="your:education-info">
        <xsl:value-of separator="&#xA;" select="
           for-each-pair(school, address, 
           function($a, $b) {$a ||  ' - ' ||  $b })" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @jun, then you should first parse it and make it xml. Most languages have a way for taking a string and turn it into xml. If it's escaped inside xml as cdata or something, you should dump it and reparse it, or use xslt 3 with parse-xml function, but that's not natively supported by python.

Comment: btw what if the xml inside education-info was written something like this &lt;school&gt;School ABC&lt/school&gt; &lt;address&gt;address123&lt;/address&gt; how can I match it? thanks.

Comment: yeah that's what im thinking of reparsing it. like for instance the namespace i been used was 'X'. X ns will not be constant will it going to change depending on the server. thanks for the idea.

Comment: @jun you are referring to the namespace prefix. It's irrelevant it changes. It only matters what it binds to, see my example code. Your bigger problem is with the embedded xml, which is next to useless until you reparse it.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (I didn't have your namespace x, so omitting it here):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="person/education-info/school">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::address[1]"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me:

```
School ABC - address 123
School ABC2 - address 456
```

EDIT: Specify [1] in following-sibling to request only first.

Comment: Be careful with `following-sibling::address`, as it will generally select *all* following siblings, i.e. when used with for-each or applying templates. Also, if run with XSLT 2.0 (version to 2.0) it will give different results. To resolve that, always add `[1]` to emphasize you only want the first following sibling.

Comment: Thanks. Edited and fixed.